# What does FixedLengthString in VB means?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Here is my sample code below. What does it checks in the if condition? Does it matches the exact value(US0980) or only matches the first two characters ("US") since the length is fixed to 2. In other words, will the if condition be satisfied?

```
    Dim strCorpCodeTemp As New VB6.FixedLengthString(2)
    strCorpCodeTemp.Value = "US0980"
    If UCase(strCorpCodeTemp.Value) = "US"
    Then
        Play Football
    Else
        Play Cricket
```

Comment: when all else fails - rtfm. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.fixedlengthstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [FixedLengthString Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.fixedlengthstring(v=vs.110).aspx)  Note that it is marked as obsolete (it is 2017, after all).  Seems like you could run that code and see how it compares

Comment: In [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.fixedlengthstring.value(v=vs.110).aspx), it sort of implies it's behavior in the example.

Comment: I suggest you also read [ask] and take the [tour] - 3 questions, 5 answers, no accepts

Comment: It is a compat class for code originally written in VB6.  You only need it if you need to read data from a binary file that was originally written by a VB6 program.  Using it for anything else is not wise.  But it behaves logically enough, it you assign a string with more than 2 chars then only the first 2 survive.  You'll trivially avoid it by using `strCorpCodeTemp.SubString(0, 2)` or `Left(strCoprCodeTemp, 2)`

Comment: @HansPassant I came across this in an existing application code.

Comment: the first result in google is showing an example with that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.fixedlengthstring.value(v=vs.110).aspx) is clear on what it does. If it will pad or truncate the string.

```
strCorpCodeTemp.Value = "U" ' Value will equal "U "
strCorpCodeTemp.Value = "US0980" ' Value will equal "US"
```

I highly suggest you stop using that class since it's obsolete.

Comment: This helps! Thanks.

Comment: The *correct* way to say 'thanks' to someone who explains the documentation to you is to click the checkmark as described in the [tour] @SubhajeetParia